# retrieve all users from parse - android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a registered app on Parse with a signup/login system. Now I want to create an activity which grabs all the available users in the app and to display them one-by-one as a listview. Can someone tell me how can I do that?

Comment: why don't you post the code that you've already tried, and I can help you

Answer (score 2):

Once you've setup your `ListView`'s adapter you can call this whenever you need to update it's contents:

```
public void updateUsers() {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> userObjects, ParseException error) {
            if (userObjects != null) {
                mUserAdapter.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < userObjects.size(); i++) {
                    mUserAdapter.add(userObjects.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

That updates my adapter which is plugged into my `ListView`. If you have more than 100 users you want to return you'll need to up the limit as I hear that's the default (then you have to page the results, not sure how yet)

**Side note:** As far as I know you can't Subclass the `ParseUser` at the moment (you can, but you then can't use that as the object you're querying with using `ParseUser.getQuery()` (Which would normally be done by `ParseUser.getQuery(MyCustomUserClass.class)` if you were to query a customised object.